# Loop in jsx that is setting an onClick

Tags: jsx

So my question is very similar to another post about a for loop in jsx.  Except in my question, I am more interested on how to set the value in the onClick method.

```
    var rows = [];
    var page_index = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       page_index = page_index + i;
       // note: we add a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
       // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
       rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} onClick = {() => props.changePage(page_index)}/>);
}
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

Basically changePage for all of the ObjectRows will be calling changePage with 15, is there a way to make page_index not a variable?  I tried to do this

```
props.changePage({page_index})
```

this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the `page_index`, I would set an initial page index and do the math portion inside of the function call like this:

```js
    var rows = [];
    var initialPageIndex = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       // note: we add a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
       // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
       rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} onClick = {() => props.changePage(initialPageIndex + i)}/>);
}
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

Comment: thanks that helped, i guess using the math operator to force it to resolve it instead of keeping it is as an variable is the way to do it.  So if i see people doing a x + 0 in the code  will know why now.